# Request Failed trying to view Favorites in iOS App when unregistered

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, bookmarks, unregistered-users

Many actions in the app require user to be logged in, and warn as such when that's not the case. For instance, when trying to vote you get "You need an account in order to vote". However, viewing Favorite Questions just fails without reason:

> [image]

Can we add a similar message about needing an account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next beta release, **1.0.1.87**

Comment: Six minutes. Wow.

Comment: It was already a known issue ;)