# Tags page fails in iOS App when unregistered

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ios-app

> [image]

It seems to be a problem on any site where I have favorite tags, but only if I'm currently logged out. Maybe it's caching my favorites somewhere and then trying to update that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next beta release, **1.0.1.87**. We definitely were not handling this usecase for unregistered users.

Comment: Dang, I thought six minutes was fast

Comment: @mhlester I bet Arie was already aware of that bug and just waited for a report. :-)

Comment: @Shadow, [why would you think that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234708/request-failed-trying-to-view-favorites-in-ios-app-when-unregistered/234710?noredirect=1#comment771762_234710) But you're just bitter because you haven't accepted Arie's challenge

Comment: @mhlester I spent whole 15 minutes hunting for bugs (logged out) in the new version (87) and man, they did a good job!

Comment: yup, no more bugs. any other ...surprises are just features